# What is the big-O time complexity of computing $1/N$ to $\log_{2}(N)$ bits of precision?

Tags: computational-complexity, periodic-functions

I am considering large integer values of $N$ (100 or more digits in base-$10$).

In my algorithm, I need to be able to compute the reciprocal of $N$ with enough precision that the repetend will have been produced exactly. (I estimate this to be to $\lfloor \log N \rfloor$ digits or $\lfloor \log_{2} N \rfloor$ bits)

If I employ ordinary long division, how may I estimate the big-$\mathcal{O}$ time complexity of calculating $\frac{1}{N}$ with the desired level of precision?

I posted [question(s) to this effect](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834120/on-the-computational-complexity-of-reciprocal) over on the Mathematics Stack Exchange, but have yet to garner an answer. I know that the complexity of the division of two $n$-digit numbers is $n^{2}$ using ordinary division, but that says nothing about the degree of precision required for non-terminating decimal expansions.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Off the bat, I'm thinking about Newton's root-finding search on $f(x)=Nx-1$, it converges very quickly, though the exact complexity might be difficult. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms

Comment: @DUO Yes. I think we can obtain as much precision as we want with Newton's Method. And if I remember correctly, that approach has Quadratic time complexity. And if I could be certain that that were also the case here, I would be happy. I'm just thinking that with the size of $N$ and the required precision, it could be worse than the complexity that Wikipedia, for example, gives for Newton's Method.

Comment: Actually, because the function is linear, it is guaranteed consistent performance (no extrema to get stuck in), as long as you start from pre-defined initial value, like $x_0=1$ or $x_0=0$. Also, you should be more concerned about space-- what are you doing with $N$ with "hundreds of digits", as you say? In addition, this is more suited for the Computer Science Stack Exchange.

Comment: The number of digits in the period of $1/N$ can be as big as $N-1$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations . The complexity is $O(M(n))$, where $n=\log N$, and $M$ is the complexity of $n\times n$ bit multiplication. The best currently known algorithm makes $M(n)=O(n\log n)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is there a theorem that for any $n$ there are infinitely many $p$ such that $n$ is a primitive root mod $p$?

Comment: Also, note that the $O(M(n))$ complexity bound is asymptotically optimal. For division $X/Y$, this follows easily from $XY=2^m/((2^m/X)/Y)$. For $1/X$, this follows from https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/25750 : an algorithm for computing $n$-bit approximations of $1/X$ for integers $X$ yields an algorithm for computing $n$-bit approximations of $1/X$ for dyadic rationals $X\in[1,2]$ of roughly the same complexity, which requires time $\Omega(M(n))$ by the linked answer.

Comment: @user no, for the simple reason that there are no primes for which $4$ is a primitive root. Even if you throw out such trivial counterexamples, there is no $n$ for which it is proved that there are infinitely many primes for which $n$ is a primitive root. But it is very strongly believed that every $n$ which isn't disqualified for trivial reasons is a primitive root for infinitely many primes, and it is known that there are at most three exceptions. Look it up!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I found that the relevant conjecture is Artin's conjecture, but otherwise have no clue where to start looking it up, as this is outside my usual area; any suggestions?

Comment: @user44191 Yes, Artin's conjecture is relevant, and there's probably a Wikipedia page on it to get you started. Hooley proved it's implied by the generalized Riemann Hypothesis, and Heath-Brown proved there are at most two (not three, as I mistakenly wrote before) prime exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote by $M_b$ the complexity of multiplying two $b$-digit integers $z = xy$. One easily sees that this is essentially obtained by convolving the $b$-dimensional vectors of digits $x*y$. The school algorithm is a "slow convolution" algorithm that takes $O(b^2)$, but fast convolution algorithms give rise to $M_b = O(b\log b)$ or $M_b = O(b\log^2 b)$ algorithms, see e.g. the [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm).

As described by [Brent](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=5103058551561005766&hl=en&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5),
whatever the complexity of your multiplication algorithm, the Newton iteration for the reciprocal also takes $M_b$ pairwise operations on digits, provided that the number $b_k$ of digits at the $k$th Newton iteration grows in the right way (i.e. geometrically). In the first few Newton iterations, the accuracy is poor so you use few bits of accuracy. As you converge to $1/x$, you use more and more bits of accuracy.

As pointed out elsewhere, the period of $1/N$ could be as large as $N$ so you're looking at $O(N\log N)$ or $O(N\log^2 N)$ running time and $O(N)$ space.

Edit: in your title, you also ask about computing $1/N$ to $O(\log(N))$ bits of accuracy, which is possibly not enough to reveal the repeating pattern of $1/N$. As per above, computing $1/N$ with $O(\log(N))$ bits of accuracy, can be achieved in just a hair more than $O(\log(N))$ digitwise operations.